# gmapping-pointcloud_to_laserscan-laser

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all.

I am just wondering whether it might be possible to use gmapping using laser and kinect/xtion pro based on pointcloud_to_laser.

I appreciate any suggestions,

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63872/gmapping-pointcloud_to_laserscan-laser/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like already mentioned you can use gmapping with kinect provided u have odometry reading. If u dont have odometry data u can use hector SLAM as it only requires laser scans..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-05-29**:
well, what I really mean is that I want to use both laser and knect to build a map with gmapping. Is it possible to use both sensors? I have a fake laser from Xtion pro using pointcloud_to_laser  and a real laser maps.

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-05-29**:
Yeah....you can but gmapping doesn't work two laser readings..

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-27**:
How to use it with out kinect, currently i have pointcloud data from database how can i use pointcloud_to_laser pacakage ?